# css media queries, one or many for mobile optimization

Tags: css, media-queries

I know that using media queries the mobile first way should make the website faster on mobile devices. I wonder if there is a difference in using a lot of media queries, like this:

```
#first {}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    #first {}
}

#second {}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    #second {}
}
```

instead of using one big one for all the desktop styles, like this:

```
#first {}

#second {}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    #first {}

    #second {}
}
```

Which is better, for the performance, or does it matter? I think that the first approach is more easy to read when dealing with lots of styles.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just in real world, the second one approach is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same thing the only thing that makes the second approach better is that you are not repeating yourself. You are keeping the code DRY and everything is located in one spot for working with that media query. Plus rewriting @media screen every time would be a pain in the ass and time consuming.

Comment: Ok, sounds good! I am editing the _s wordpress theme which comes with the scss-files separated in a lot of files. Therefore I think it is more clear to me to at least use one media query in each file. In the end there would be quite many queries when compiled I guess.